# Using Pandas " | " operator between two boolean Series objects behaving strangely

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have two large pandas Series.

```
In [32]: mask.shape
Out[32]: (13919455,)

In [33]: t.shape
Out[33]: (13919455,)
```

Both are bool arrays, mask is only False, while t contains a few True values

```
In [28]: sum(mask)
Out[28]: 0

In [29]: sum(t)
Out[29]: 7724
```

I would expect that when I apply the pandas OR operator, | , I would get a sum of 7724 and that the operator is commutative.
However, I get the following result:

```
In [44]: sum(mask|t)
Out[44]: 7565

In [45]: sum(t | mask)
Out[45]: 7724
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: do both pd.Series have the same index values?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out, its a "feature" of how pandas must do OR operations.
It turned out that I had previously dropped some rows from "t", and while it was the same size as the other variable, its index was slightly larger.

After dropping the index to a default using Series.reset_index(), I get the results initially expected.

Comment: we all find that one out, sometimes its the hard way :)